# Android how to make hint filling by typed text

Tags: android, text, mask, maskedinput

I want show hint of EditText and when user enter text show part of entered and part of masked hint.

Example i got hint like

```
(___) ___-__-__
```

I want on EditText when user enter 985 446 EditText shows

```
(985) 446-__-__
```

I can't found solutions.

[image]

Look at picture, user already entered +7 (985) 446 but still needs enter last part oh mobile phone number, and it's part is grayed, but showed.

In standart behavior in Android EditText with masked or not, we get next picture (EditText set hint +7 (**_) _** -**-**)

[image]

but when i will enter first char (+ for example) i got next picture

[image]

And it's not what i need.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK EditText does not have this ability so the best thing you could do is to format the text with [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) as the numbers are input

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of answers in google, did you try one of those:

- http://horribile.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-mask-with-edittext.html
- https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText

Comment: No it's not a solution. Because not big deal make masked text, i want spanned text, with part of entered user text, and part of less of mask.